# не получается в pandas найти среднее значение

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, анализ-данных

вот код:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url,sep=';')

df.describe()
```

`pd.concat(df, axis=1).mean(axis=1)` вот эта штука не работает, как и эта `df[df['alcohol'] == 1].mean()`
нужно найти среднее значение столбца alcohol. Можно воспользоваться describe, но хочется, чтобы отдельно выводилось среднее значение, максимальное, минимальное, доля чего-либо. Чет хз как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Среднее значение столбца `alcohol`:

```
In [13]: df["alcohol"].mean()
Out[13]: 10.422983114446502
```

Минимум, среднее, медиана, максимум и стандартное отклонение столбца `alcohol` одной командой:

```
In [14]: df["alcohol"].agg(["min", "mean", "median", "max", "std"])
Out[14]:
min        8.400000
mean      10.422983
median    10.200000
max       14.900000
std        1.065668
Name: alcohol, dtype: float64
```

Чтобы вывести отдельно:

```
In [15]: df["alcohol"].median()
Out[15]: 10.2

In [16]: df["alcohol"].std()
Out[16]: 1.0656675818473926
```